# Using attributes from the derived class in the base class

Tags: python, inheritance

In the project I'm working on, we have a hierarchy of classes with each class defining a `get_text()` method.

```
class Base:
    def get_text(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Derived1(Base):
    def get_text(self):
        return "Text from Derived1"

class Derived2(Base):
    def get_text(self):
        return "Text from Derived2"

obj1 = Derived1()
print(obj1.get_text())
==> 'Text from Derived1'

obj2 = Derived2()
print(obj2.get_text())
==> 'Text from Derived2'
```

This way, the programmer can call `obj.get_text()` and get the text from the class `obj` is pointing to.

Now I want to refactor the method to be just an attribute (called `TEXT`). I want to keep the original methods for backward compatibility, though. Is there a way to do it in the base class only?

```
class Base:
    def get_text(self):
        """
        Keep backward compatibility.
        """
        return TEXT  # What should be here?

class Derived1(Base):
    TEXT = "Text from Derived1"

class Derived2(Base):
    TEXT = "Text from Derived2"

obj1 = Derived1()
print(obj1.TEXT)

# Non-refactored code
obj2 = Derived2()
print(obj2.get_text())
==> NameError: name 'TEXT' is not defined
```

Coming from C++, I'm used to having a pointer to the base class invoke a method from the derived class using C++ virtual method dispatching. Is something similar possible in Python?

Comment: ...`self.TEXT`?

Comment: What @jonrsharpe said, `self.TEXT`

Comment: @jonrsharpe - yes, it's that easy! Got caught in the C++ model and could not see the obvious answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question (thanks to the commenters!) both following ways work:

```
return self.__class__.TEXT
```

Here, `self.__class__` points either to `Derived1` or to `Derived2` class objects, which have access to `TEXT`.

```
return self.TEXT
```

makes this one step shorter, as the attribute resolution algorithm accesses class attributes automatically.